# Source script on a specific filetype without .vimrc modification

Tags: vimscript, filetype

Is there a mechanism that I can use in vim/gvim which lets me automatically source a specific script file when I open a file of certain type?

I have a specific file format (a subtype of XML) and when I edit these files, I want to create some other key mappings/bindings without cluttering the .vimrc. I thought there maybe is a mechanism to drop my script into a subdirectory of ~/.vim that automatically get sourced (so that I can decide in my script if I execute it or not)?

Secondly, is there an option to only execute my code for a specific "flavor" of XML? For example, my XML files are distinctly recognizable because apart from being XML they also have a specific namespace that appears in the header. Ideally I would only want my keybindings to become effective on that subtype, is that possible?

Comment: On the second part, it's rather a matter of taste if you define a different (sub-)filetype by examining file contents in ftdetect script or do the same in ftplugin xml script before deciding if your keybindings should be set up or not.

Comment: Either way, the filetype plugin mechanism is definitely the way to go. You can use a custom filetype as hinted or have a standard filetype whose plugin augments bindings in certain situations. I’ll try to flesh this out later.

Comment: Thank you so much, perfect solution!